# Import namespace in CoffeeScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, coffeescript

Is it possible to import a namespace for a JavaScript / CoffeeScript file?
The idea is to avoid typing out the fully qualified namespaces.

Let's say I have defined the bellow in my init code.

```
window.Editor = { }
```

And this is the CoffeeScript file in which I want to avoid having to type the fully qualified namespaces over and over again:

```
class Editor.Editor
  constructor: (@width, @hight) ->
    @canvas = new Editor.Canvas(@width,  @hight)
    @backGround = new Editor.BackGround(@canvas)
    @frontGround = new Editor.FrontGround(@canvas)
```

Can I import a namespace similar to how you would import a package in Java for example

```
import Editor.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Editor.coffee:

```
Editor = {}

root = exports ? window
root.Editor = Editor
```

main.coffee:

```
{Editor} = require './Editor'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for key, value of Editor
  window[key] = value
```

But you should be **really carefull**. Because you can redefine something you really need.